# Node esBuild suddenly failing with FSLegacyMainResolve problem

Tags: node.js, gitlab, tsc, esbuild

I have a Node project that builds fine locally, and has historically built with no problems on the GitLab CI/CD server.  However, suddenly, the pipeline build fails on the server with no changes to the code.  I even opened several branches for past commits that previously built fine, and they also fail on the server.

I'm mostly trying to understand what this error "means":

```
const resolvedOption = FSLegacyMainResolve(packageJsonUrlString, packageConfig.main, baseStringified);
                         ^
TypeError: The URL must be of scheme file: <etc...>
```

I have to assume something changed in the build environment, it's not able to pull down a package suddenly, or similar, but there's nothing really specific about what the problem might be. I'm looking for pointers about why this is occurring, and possibly how to troubleshoot.

Relevant error from the log on the build server is:

```
$ npm install
added 362 packages, and audited 363 packages in 17s
47 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ echo "Compile complete."
Compile complete.
$ npm run build
> my-project@1.0.0 build
> tsc -skipLibCheck && node esbuild.config.mjs production && npm pack
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:205
  const resolvedOption = FSLegacyMainResolve(packageJsonUrlString, packageConfig.main, baseStringified);
                         ^
TypeError: The URL must be of scheme file:
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:205:26)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:831:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:901:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1121:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME'
}
Node.js v20.10.0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Again, this runs just fine locally, same version of Node.js, etc. I've cleared local npm cache, deleted node_modules, etc, all in an attempt to potentially replicate the server-side state, but still everything works fine locally.

Comment: This appears to be nothing to do with my project or its dependencies, this looks like a sudden issue that cropped up yesterday with NodeJS and Alpine Linux (which is the container runner I'm using):

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51096

https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/15558

Answer (score -1):

Got similar issue when I'm using node 20.x in my docker container (alpine).
Use Node 18.x and it just works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).